# C++ Passing an Object to Another Object From Another Class

Tags: c++

I am trying to write this program using base classes and derived classes where there is a truck with a maximum capacity of 8 tons. Then this truck is loaded with 1.5 tons of apple and then loaded with 0.5 tons of kiwi. This would then diminish the amount of  tons remaining to 6.5 when the apples are loaded and then to 6 when the kiwis are loaded. This is an assignment and in the main function I see they are calling the function `loadCargo` as follows `truck.loadCargo(Apple())`, I am unsure of what this is accomplishing. Please take a look at the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Cargo{
public:
    double c = 0;
    double getAmount(){
        return c;
}
};


class Apple : public Cargo{
public:
    double c = 1.5;
    double getAmount(){
        return c;
}
};

class Kiwi : public Cargo{
public:
    double c = 0.5;
    double getAmount(){
        return c;
        }
}; 

class Truck {
    double maxCapacity = 8;
public:
    void loadCargo(Cargo cargo){
    maxCapacity = maxCapacity - cargo.getAmount();
}
        void printInfo(){
            cout << maxCapacity << " tons remaining" << endl;
        }
};


int main() {
    Truck truck;
    truck.printInfo();

        truck.loadCargo(Apple());
        truck.printInfo();

        truck.loadCargo(Kiwi());
        truck.printInfo();
}
```

I thought that `truck.loadCargo(Apple())` would pass an object of Apple to the object cargo. Therefore when `loadCargo` is called, it would access the `getAmount` function in Apple class and not in class Cargo but that is not happening. The output should be:

```
8 tons remaining
6.5 tons remaining
6 tons remaining
```

But currently it is the following since it just using the `getAmount` from the Cargo class:

```
8 tons remaining
8 tons remaining
8 tons remaining
```

EDIT: Since this is an assignment I cannot change anything in the main function or in the line that has `void loadCargo(Cargo cargo)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make your `getAmount()` function virtual:

```
class Cargo{
public:
    double c = 0;
    virtual double getAmount(){
        return c;
    }
};
```

Then, your derived classes will override the `getAmount()` function with their version.

Without the `virtual` keyword, if your function accepts a parameter of type `Cargo`, it will just used the `Cargo::getAmount()` function.

Second, you need to pass your object into by const-reference, like this:

```
class Truck {
    double maxCapacity = 8;
public:
    void loadCargo(const Cargo& cargo){
        maxCapacity = maxCapacity - cargo.getAmount();
    }
    ...
```

This will ensure that your `cargo` object inside the `loadCargo` function will refer to an `Apple` object or a `Kiwi` object. By passing by value, you're copying your `Apples` object into a `Cargo` object, and you fall over the [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

ETA: You would also need to change your `getAmount()` function to `const` like this:

```
//                 vvvvv
double getAmount() const {
    return c;
}
```

---

**Since you mention you cannot change your Truck class**, you can do this by setting the value of `c` in your Cargo class constructor. Like this:

```
class Cargo{
public:
    double c;

    // Constructor, using an initializer list to set the value of `c`.
    Cargo(const double c_value) :
        c(c_value) {
    }

    double getAmount(){
        return c;
    }
};
```

Then, in your `Apple` and `Kiwi` classes, set the value of `c` inside the constructor, like this:

```
class Apple : public Cargo{
public:
    // Set the Cargo's mass in the Apple constructor...
    Apple() :
        Cargo(1.5) {
    }

    // getAmount() function removed.
};
```

Finally, remove the `getAmount()` functions from your `Apple` and `Kiwi` classes (but KEEP for the `Cargo` class).

**Final Note**

Please bear in mind that passing Cargo by value will always suffer from the Slicing Problem (see link above) and should be avoided, though because your `Apple` and `Kiwi` objects don't have any member variables, it will still work for your assignment. If inheritance is how your instructor wanted this to work, then passing `Cargo` by value into `loadCargo(Cargo cargo)` is *bad C++ practice*. This doesn't impact your assignment, but if you wish to take C++ seriously, bear this in mind for the future!

Comment: I am getting ```error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Cargo&' to an rvalue of type 'Cargo'|```. Also, I would like to avoid changing the implementation of ``void loadCargo(Cargo cargo)`` since this is an assignment and I am not supposed to alter that line.

Comment: @Rivf I have added an extra part to my answer that avoids changing the `loadCargo()` function :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you make this call:

```
truck.loadCargo(Apple());
```

You are indeed passing an `Apple` to `truck`. However, the declaration of `loadCargo` takes a `Cargo` object:

```
void loadCargo(Cargo cargo)
```

This slices the `Apple` and now you simply have a `Cargo` object that you call `getAmount` on. This returns 0, and so the `maxCapacity` doesn't change.

There are various ways to fix this, but the simplest would be to make `loadCargo` a template, so that it can accept any type without first converting it to a `Cargo` object:

```
template<typename Fruit>
void loadCargo(Fruit cargo)
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hqq9EY).

---

Note that for this implementation, so long as `Apple` and `Kiwi` have the same member functions as expected of a `Cargo` object, you can avoid inheriting from a base class entirely.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. Is it possible to do this without altering the ``void loadCargo(Cargo cargo)``? As I mentioned this is an assignment and it is prohibited to change that line.

Comment: @Rivf Oh, you can't change `Truck` either? Are you sure? Accepting a `Cargo` by value is not going to work, I think. See the other answer, maybe that's what you're looking for. You'll still have to change the definition of `loadCargo` though.

Comment: I can change the contents of ``class Truck``, I just can't mess with that one line that contains ``void loadCargo(Cargo cargo)``.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show *exactly* which parts of the code are fixed, and which parts you wrote?